# How to copy a custom field from the user's CPT to the user's normal posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-type

Each author has a single post in a CPT. In their CPT post they have a custom field.

Each author can also post to a normal post  type as much as they like.

How can I copy the custom field of the user's CPT post copied to all their normal post type posts they subsequently post.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `wp_insert_post` action for when a user creates/saves a "normal" post, then find their custom post and copy over any fields you need:

```
function wpse_203349_copy_post_meta( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    if ( $post->post_type !== 'post' )
        return;

    $users_custom_posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_author' => $post->post_author,
            'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
        )
    );

    if ( ! $users_custom_posts )
        return; // This author doesn't currently have any custom posts

    $fields = get_post_custom( $users_custom_posts[0]->ID );

    foreach ( $fields as $field => $value ) {
        if ( $field[0] !== '_' && ( empty( $value[0] ) || ! is_array( $value[0] ) ) ) // Ignore "private" fields (prefixed with an underscore or serialized data)
            add_post_meta( $post_ID, $field, empty( $value[0] ) ? '' : $value[0], true /* Unique */ ); // If the field already exists, it won't be overwritten, unlike update_post_meta()
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wpse_203349_copy_post_meta', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it's copying the custom field, but not the value of the field.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Still no values, oh and it triplicates every custom field of the new post when I publish it. Hot Diggity!

Comment: [line 2] `if ( $post->post_type !== 'post' )` ... this doesn't change right? I've only edited the CPT name in line 9

Comment: Each time the post is updated it adds more copies of the post's custom fields.

Comment: Whoops, need a fourth argument `true` for unique

Comment: The custom field names are being copied and are not replicating, but... Still no values in the fields.

Comment: We're getting there. I totally misread your original comment as "don't want the value"... try revised answer.

Comment: Rightio... It is copying the last posted CPT fields regardless of who the author is.

Comment: As well... I'm using the WordPress User Front End Pro plugin to post  the CPT posts and the normal posts. When I try to publish a normal post from the front end plugin it throws an error and doesn't allow me to  publish it via the front end, but I just can via the back end.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: It's an error from the plugin telling me I can post from the front end, I think the function needs this... http://docs.wedevs.com/using-action-hook-field/#step-3-saving-our-input

Comment: I also asked on the WP forums and it said "The argument is 'author', not 'post_author'! :) Thus it is ignored and the query returns anyone's post. Half the other arguments are post_something, but not author X>"

Comment: It's an error from the plugin telling me I CANT post from the front end,